# Using Model with a Partial View - The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Another nerddinner noob here. I've made it through the example nerddinner project and am starting to create a new similar thing that I need.

So, my index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ProjectSender.Models.Incident>
...
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.IncidentId })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Partial("_ReserveStatusList", item)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My partial view looks like this:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ProjectSender.Models.Incident>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function AnimateProjectMessage() {
        $("#projectmsg").animate({ fontSize: "1.5em" }, 400);
    }

</script>
<div id="projectmsg">


        @Ajax.ActionLink("Reserve this Project",
                             "Reserve", "Projects",
                                      new { id = item.IncidentId },
                             new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "projectmsg", OnSuccess = "AnimateProjectMessage" })

</div>
```

If I replace the partial view and just use the `Ajax.ActionLink` in the `index.cshtml`, it works ok. However, if I use it in the partial view, for `item (in item.IncidentId)` I get *"The name item does not exist in the current context."* However, there are no red squiggles in VS. I get this error in the browser.

If you're comparing this to nerddinner, I'm basically trying to drop the RSVP option for each dinner inside the list of Dinners. The RSVP partial view is normally on the Details page.

**Edit:** for the sake of being complete. Here is my controller code as requested in case someone is looking at this in the future:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, int? page)
        {
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            IQueryable<Incident> incidents = null;

            incidents = incidentRepository.FindRecentIncidents(searchString);

            return View(incidents.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

Ultimately, after upgrading from MVC3/EF4 to MVC4/EF4 and putting the partial view back to the original nerddinner code (as was suggested in the accepted answer), all is ok.

Comment: please post your controller action method also .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in partial there is no `item` defined. Partial view receives it as a model (fix your partial's model to be just a single `Incident` btw - you are not passing a list in there), so you need to use `Model` to refer to the item passed instead:

```
@model ProjectSender.Models.Incident
...
@Ajax.ActionLink("Reserve this Project",
                     "Reserve", "Projects",
                              new { id = Model.IncidentId },
```

Comment: Hmm, no effect, that's what it originally was and I was getting this error in MVC3: (pagedlist.ipagedlist<model> does not contain a definition for <model>). Sorry, paraphrasing, I only chopped out the part of the error that would help me in google. Doing what I did above made that error go away. I then changed from MVC3 to MVC4 (both using EF4) and it definitely helped. But, I changed so much stuff leading up to that, it's looking like I need to backtrack some. With your answer though, I can at least focus somewhere else. If you have any other ideas, I'm all ears. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Doh, sorry, you are 100% correct. I changed the @Model portion up top, but missed changing "item" to "Model". Once doing so, everything works as expected and that's how the original nerddinner code is too. So, I think MVC3 and EF4 don't play nicely together? Anyway, many thanks, I can now move on to greener pastures...